# Collection getSize() returns weird data

Tags: magento2, collection

Well, here is `getSize()` definition inside `AbstractDb` class

```
public function getSize()
    {
        if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = $this->_totalRecords ?? $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);

        }

        return (int)$this->_totalRecords;
    }
```

It's clear that if `_totalRecords` value is null, so it goes to run `getSelectCountSql()` query to get count and save it in `_totalRecords` to reload it again once need.
I logged the query used to get count and it's similar to the query which already get the product collection however the real collection count is just 2 products which is correct after applying filters, but `getSize()` returns 6 products which is total products I have.

```
    2021-05-27T20:43:27+00:00 INFO (6): 6---->SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = '4' AND price_index.website_id = '1'
 INNER JOIN `ul_current_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.sales_entity = '2' WHERE ((stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)
```

this is the log for the first query ran in the `getSize()` method. _totalRecords = 6 however when running this query it returns 2
Any clues on what's happening here ?

Comment: this function is just for check "is collection empty or not??  what u want to achieve?

Comment: use `collection->count()`

Comment: @RizwanKhan `$collection->getSize()` already used in Toolbar.
I figured out that `getSize()` query returns the correct number but the problem is with `_totalRecords` which was already populated from CatalogSearch `_renderFiltersBefore` before reaching `getSize()` statment. that's a weird logic from Magento